# How to realize "B ping C " when running flask on A?

Tags: flask, ping

I'm developing a RESTful API using flask.
The flask service is running on server A and this API should test the network connectivity between the client(B) and a certain server(C). How can I realize it?

The difficulty is how to ping from a remote server to another remote server.

Comment: Your post is contradictory. You say that you want to ping from client(B) to server(C), but then you say that you want to ping from remote server to another server. Please make your question clear if you want us to answer.

Comment: Sorry, it should be "ping from a remote client(B) to another server(C)".

Comment: so why do not you just try to access some http resource of server C from client B using ajax for instance?

Comment: Client B is not accessible to me. Instead, the flask service wants to provide network connectivity test for the Client. So every time the Client calls the API, the connectivity status is returned. Is there a way to achieve that?